# Python/Pandas remove the start of a string which contains a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
COLUMN NAME
Sample\Sample_ID\
Sample\Sample_ID\
Sample\Sample_ID\
Sample\Sample_ID\
Sample_ID\
Sample_ID\
```

I want remove/strip "Sample\" for the lines of data which contain this.

Comment: This will throw an error because of the backslash @dan_g

Comment: Yes for a big part, only difference here is that OP was stuck on the backslash as text character and not escape character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['COLUMN NAME'] = df['COLUMN NAME'].str.replace(r'Sample\\', '')
```

**Output**

```
    COLUMN NAME
0   Sample_ID\
1   Sample_ID\
2   Sample_ID\
3   Sample_ID\
4   Sample_ID\
5   Sample_ID\
```

**Note**

I use double baslash `\\` since a single backslash is an escape character in Python. So we need to use two to literally point to a single backslash.

Comment: Thank you - this part was key : (r'Sample\\', '')
I kept getting an error with only this: ('Sample\', '')

Comment: Glad I could help, if this answered your question you can accept it as an answer :) @AmieJohnson

Comment: Please test before commenting, this will raise an error `error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 6` @dan_g

Comment: Does this really work? Since you used both the `r` raw prefix **and** the double backslashes `\\\`? This should result in 2 (real) backslashes being searched for, whereas only one is in the actual text.

Comment: Yes I agree, did not expect either. I tried `r'  '` first and after that double backslash. Both gave an error. You can try with the example dataframe and my code. Apparently it runs correct for OP as well. @Jeronimo